# Como deixar um slideshow acessível a toques em smartphones?

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber se tem como deixar um slideshow em touch quando alguém acessa pelo smartphone ! E também se tem como fazer isso com javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um conselho, não tente reinventar a pólvora, se estiver a desenvolver websites. para websites responsivos, poderá facilmente optar por uma solução tipo WHMCS, ou Wordpress, e criar uma conta de aloJamento num servidor ftp, instalar um template como o total, ou o betheme, e a partir daí, incluir código, a partir de exemplos de repositórios do Github, podendo sempre acrescentar ferramentas como bootstrap, mongodb, angular, node ou ruby on rails. não há nada mais simples, e conseguirá concerteza ter um produto pronto em menos de um dia.

Comment: a resposta anterior parte do princípio que está a construir um website, ou uma versão de um website, a correr em mobile, e que quer aceder ao website em smartphones

Comment: se quiser fazer isso numa aplicação para android ou iOS, deverá encontrar exemplos no github e no codecanyon, sobre como incorporar slideshows responsivos em smartphones

Comment: vlw pessoal, pelas dicas e ajuda !!

Answer (score 0):

O jQuery tem suporte a [eventos de touch](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp), porem dependendo do que você deseja fazer talvez seja possível [somente com CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action).

Comment: brigado tirou minhas duvidas e percebi que o css é uma linguagem poderosa !!

Comment: Tem certeza que isso resolveu seu problema?

Comment: sim. era que oque queria saber !!

Answer (score 0):

O [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) é um plugin que permite criar slides, carousels, responsivos. Ele funciona junto com jQuery então é necessário ter o jQuery nos seus scripts.

Comment: achei legal esse puglin !!

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando jQuery para construir o script do slideshow, além do evento click, adicione também o evento touchend.